# Handler brings up the Intent all the time

Tags: android, android-intent, handler

When I refresh my activity class to intake some MySQL variables the activity gets refreshed just fine, as expected, every 60 seconds, but the annoying part about it is, even if I'm not currently focused on the app, or even on another app, the activity keeps popping up and closing the activity I'm currently working at. Is there anything I can do in the xml or the Handler method itself to make the app do the refresh in the background or an alternative?

Here is the Handler method from within the onCreate method;

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
final Runnable r = new Runnable()
{
public void run() 
{
    json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(i);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 60000);
}
};
handler.postDelayed(r, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the runnables keep executing even when the application goes in the background. So, the idea is to cancel the runnables whenever this happens.

**Solution :**

Inside onPause() :
`handler.removeCallbacks(r);`

Inside onResume() :
`handler.postDelayed(r)`

This'll ensure that whenever the Activity is minimized/goes off the screen, there'll be no refreshing but it'll start once you reach the activity again.

Comment: when they are in the onPause and onResume method, handler and r cannot be resolved because they are not public variables, when I make them public, I cannot make them final. Any thoughts?

Comment: Declare them as instance variables.

Comment: what's the exception ? can you post the logcat trace ?